# Drawer activity on API Level 19

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat

I've changed my minimum SDK from 21 to 19 and in 19API the toggle button and toolbar (to open the menu) in the drawer activity doesn't appear.

API >21[toggle and Toolbar appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM00w.png)

API 19 [nothing shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ99Z.png)

My layouts are two files: app_bar_main and content_main

APP_BAR_MAIN

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="gchmapplications.hermandadsantamariavictoria.Actividades.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

CONTENT_MAIN

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contenedor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

I've tried with other configurations and it doesn't solve the problem, BUT the thing is that it exists in the view but is showed 'out of the screen' because when I change some values it appears above the toolbar [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM00w.png)

---

I've noticed that doing from zero the tutorial that I followed (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aLFCpaoOZo) in API19 doesn't appear so the problem is the tutorial I followed.

Comment: Please don't include the solution in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the below-mentioned codes to fulfill your implementation:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="in.assamtourism.atdc_demo.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="left">

<RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#b71c1c"
            android:theme="@style/DrawerArrowStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#8c000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<!--All Your UI codes should be here-->

</RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/myNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="#e53935"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then declare these variables in "YourActivity".java file:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
```

And in the onCreate method, add these lines:

```
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.myDrawerLayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.myNavigationView);
        navigationView.getMenu().clear();
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.nav_menu);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        );
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Once it is done, customize according to your needs.

Comment: The xml I supppouse would be App_bar_main.xml no?

Comment: I've tried and it solves the toolbar problem, but how I combine it now with my coordinator layout for the tabbed activity?

Comment: I've managed to do it finally. I changed relative layout to linear and the textview with the CoordinatorLayout and the AppbarLayout inside it. I had to remove the toolbar inside the coordinator layout.

Comment: I haven't done it yet because I dont know why now the layout is bigger than the screen on the bottom. I have a margin of 5dp in most of the views and now it cuts the margin and a little bit of the content... (I post a new comment with a picture)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why now the layout is bigger than the screen on the bottom. I have a margin of 5dp in most of the views and now it cuts the margin and a little bit of the content...

[image]

This is the actual activity_main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="#981e73be"
    app:itemTextColor="#2E2E2E"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: I've post it here, it's not really the answer because it displays wrong in the screen. It can't be the answer yet.

Comment: try the implementation that i have suggested and see the video tutorial link that i have posted.

Comment: My code is the same implemention as yours except RelativeLayout and Textview (because I need the container). I'll try again with RelativeLayout but before didnt work

Comment: Your first edits doesnt work. I'll try whith the second ones.

Comment: See my new answer. It will surely solve your problem

Comment: Thanks :) I fixed with my intuition

Comment: Please edit your question to update or provide additional information. Please don't post it as an answer.